# Why are there broken packages while reinstalling without formatting original home directory?

Tags: 14.04, apt

I used Ubuntu 15.04, but it crushed. I want to use a more stabilized operating system, so I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04. While I was installing Ubuntu 14.04, I formatted the "/" directory and used the original "/home" directory without formatting. But when I type

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

It occurred an error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

python3-pip : Depends: python3-setuptools but it is not going to be installed

          Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed

          Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I just typed the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And I tried again, the same error occurred. So I tried "aptitude" as follows:

```
sudo aptitude install python3-pip

The following NEW packages will be installed:   build-essential{a} dpkg-dev{ab} g++{a} g++-4.8{ab}    libalgorithm-diff-perl{a} libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl{a}    libalgorithm-merge-perl{a} libexpat1-dev{ab} libpython3-dev{a}    libpython3.4-dev{ab} libstdc++-4.8-dev{ab} python3-colorama{a}    python3-dev{a} python3-distlib{a} python3-html5lib{a} python3-pip    python3-requests{a} python3-setuptools{ab} python3-urllib3{a}    python3.4-dev{ab}

0 packages upgraded, 20 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.9 MB of archives. After unpacking 77.2 MB will be used.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libstdc++-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is installed.
                     Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is installed.

libpython3.4-dev : Depends: libpython3.4-stdlib (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1) but 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 is installed.
                    Depends: libpython3.4 (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1) but 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 is installed.

dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.17.5ubuntu5) but 1.17.5ubuntu5.4 is installed.

python3.4-dev : Depends: python3.4 (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1) but 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 is installed.
                 Depends: libpython3.4 (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1) but 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 is installed.

libexpat1-dev : Depends: libexpat1 (= 2.1.0-4ubuntu1) but 2.1.0-4ubuntu1.1 is installed.

g++-4.8 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is installed.
           Depends: gcc-4.8 (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is installed.

python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 3.3-1ubuntu1) but 3.3-1ubuntu2 is installed.

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
     Keep the following packages at their current version:

1)      build-essential [Not Installed]                    
2)      dpkg-dev [Not Installed]                           
3)      g++ [Not Installed]                                
4)      g++-4.8 [Not Installed]                            
5)      libexpat1-dev [Not Installed]                      
6)      libpython3-dev [Not Installed]                     
7)      libpython3.4-dev [Not Installed]                   
8)      libstdc++-4.8-dev [Not Installed]                  
9)      python3-dev [Not Installed]                        
10)     python3-pip [Not Installed]                        
11)     python3-setuptools [Not Installed]                 
12)     python3.4-dev [Not Installed]                      
      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
13)     python3-pip recommends build-essential             
14)     python3-pip recommends python3-dev (>= 3.2)        


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y

No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

I typed "Y" to accept the solution, but there was nothing happened to fix the broken packages. How to make it?

---

```
kl@kali:~$ apt-cache policy python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev build-essential

python3-pip: 
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 1.5.4-1
Version table:
   1.5.4-1 0
      500 http://ftp.sjtu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
python3-setuptools:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 3.3-1ubuntu1
Version table:
 3.3-1ubuntu1 0
    500 http://ftp.sjtu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
python3-dev: 
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 3.4.0-0ubuntu2
Version table:
 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 0
    500 http://ftp.sjtu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
build-essential:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 11.6ubuntu6
Version table:
   11.6ubuntu6 0
      500 http://ftp.sjtu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

---

```
kl@kali:~$ apt-cache policy libstdc++-4.8-dev gcc-4.8-base
libstdc++-4.8-dev:
 Installed: (none)
Candidate: 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
Version table:
 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
    500 http://ftp.sjtu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
gcc-4.8-base:
  Installed: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
  Version table:
 *** 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
    500 http://ftp.sjtu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

---

```
kl@kali:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base=4.8.2-19ubuntu1 libgcc-4.8-dev=4.8.2-19ubuntu1 gcc-4.8=4.8.2-19ubuntu1
[sudo] password for kl: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.8 : Depends: cpp-4.8 (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
        Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (>= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libgcc-4.8-dev : Depends: libgomp1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libitm1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libatomic1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libasan0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libtsan0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libquadmath0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev build-essential`

Comment: @A.B.   I've done that:-)

Comment: The next one `apt-cache policy libstdc++-4.8-dev gcc-4.8-base`

Comment: What's your Ubuntu distribution? Kali?

Comment: @A.B. It's Ubuntu-gnome 14.04, I just name it "Kali".

Comment: Use my answer and give me the output or the problems by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache policy libpython3.4-dev libpython3.4-stdlib libpython3.4`

Comment: And [edit] your question again and add the output of `apt-cache policy gcc-4.8-base libgcc-4.8-dev gcc-4.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### not solved, see below

1. Downgrade `gcc-4.8-base`, `libgcc-4.8-dev` and `gcc-4.8`, you need version `4.8.2-19ubuntu1` and not the (manually?) installed version `4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base=4.8.2-19ubuntu1 libgcc-4.8-dev=4.8.2-19ubuntu1 gcc-4.8=4.8.2-19ubuntu1
   ```
2. Repair

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
3. Install `python3-pip`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python3-pip
   ```

---

OPs decision: reinstall of the system

Comment: I have to add the output of the command above.

Comment: I just reinstall Ubuntu 15.04, so that I make it. Thanks for your advice:-)

Comment: Ok. Also a way. ;)

Comment: @socket If you have to reinstall everything, try to blow up `~/.cache` first: it's completely a shot in the dark, but it might be that something in there is causing this

Comment: @kos I get it:-)

Comment: I could install it after using this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/34670459/2886003